# How does Airflow's BranchPythonOperator work?

Tags: airflow

I'm struggling to understand how BranchPythonOperator in Airflow works. I know it's primarily used for branching, but am confused by the documentation as to what to pass into a task and what I need to pass/expect from the task upstream.

Given the simple example in the documentation [on this page](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#branching) what would the source code look like for the upstream task called `run_this_first` and the 2 downstream ones that are branched? How exactly does Airflow know to run `branch_a` instead of `branch_b`? Where does the upstream task's` output get noticed/read?

Comment: here is nice example https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py

Answer (score 34):

Your BranchPythonOperator is created with a `python_callable`, which will be a function.  That function shall return, based on your business logic, the task name of the immediately downstream tasks that you have connected.  This could be 1 to N tasks immediately downstream.  There is nothing that the downstream tasks *HAVE* to read, however you could pass them metadata using xcom.

```
def decide_which_path():
    if something is True:
        return "branch_a"
    else:
        return "branch_b"


branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='run_this_first',
    python_callable=decide_which_path,
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    dag=dag)

branch_task.set_downstream(branch_a)
branch_task.set_downstream(branch_b)
```

It's important to set the `trigger_rule` or all of the rest will be skipped, as the default is `all_success`.

Comment: Is that still true regarding the trigger_rule? The docs don't suggest you need that, but just a dummy task, because the other tasks (apart from the one returned by the function) immediately downstream will be skipped https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#branching

Comment: Yes, that is correct, so it depends on how the downstream tasks are connected.  I think I assumed that all of the branches merged back into a main line of tasks, but that probably isn't even the normal use case (but it is my normal one).

Comment: what's your usecase out of interest? My current one is 'does this file exist' and if it doesn't, proceed to create it, otherwise dummy task then dag exits successfully. It's specifically for loading some static data (will never change) from a SQL database to hadoop. I want it idempotent, with a very quick no-op, avoiding query impact to the source database completely if not needed.

Comment: I have a series of chunks where any failure is not fatal, and should continue through each branch operation.  I have 3 branches for each chunk, 2 success paths depending on task output, and 1 failure branch. these three merge back into the next branch operator until all defined chunks are complete.

Comment: What if my branch condition depends on something that happens in a task that's upstream of the branch operator?

Example:
    check_some_files >> process_duplicates_found (OR) do_nothing

Comment: @punkrockpolly - check out XComs @ https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html  (use Ctrl+F xcoms to find it fast)  XComs are great for small signals and data sizes.  You can also use external systems like redis or a database to perform the communication between tasks.  Your usecase will help determine which way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much! `It's important to set the` `trigger_rule` `or all the rest will be skipped, as the default is` `all_success` was exactly what I needed!