# Why is an airflow downstream task done even if branch tasks fail and trigger rule is one succes?

Tags: airflow

I worked my way through an [example script on BranchPythonOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_branch_operator.py) and I noticed the following:

The final task gets Queued before the the follow_branch_x task is done. This I found strange, because before queueing the final task, it should know whether its upstream task is a succes (TriggerRule is ONE_SUCCESS).

To test this, I replaced the 3 of the 4 follow_branch_ tasks with tasks that would fail, and noticed that regardless of the follow_x branch task state, the downstream task gets done. See the image:

[image: failed_branch_task_results_in_downstream_done]

Could anyone explain this behaviour to me, as it does not feel intuitive as normally failed tasks prevent downstream tasks from being executed.

Code defining the join task:

```
join = DummyOperator(
    task_id = "join",
    trigger_rule = TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: I think I read somewhere about a bug like this, but cannot find that reference right now. Why are the other tasks with this light border color (branch_b - branch_d and following)?

Comment: Light background colors are because of the different Operators. Pink for PythonOperator (which raises an Exception) and Light green for DummyOperator. The pink border indicates skipped tasks. You can see the legend of this in the upper left part of the image.

Comment: I meant something different: Why is the *border* lightly colored?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `trigger_rule` to `all_done` on your branching operator like this:

```
branch_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branching',
    python_callable=decide_which_path(),
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    dag=dag)
```

No idea if this will work but it seems to have helped some people out before:

[How does Airflow's BranchPythonOperator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526354/how-does-airflows-branchpythonoperator-work)

Answer (score 1):

Definition from [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#core-ideas)

1. `one_success`: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done

If you continue to use `one_success`, you need all of your four `follow_branch-x` tasks to fail for `join` not to be run.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct - the documentation states: "one_success: fires as soon as at least one parent succeeds, it does not wait for all parents to be done" 

A "parent" is the task immediately before the task in question. In this case `branch_a` is the "grand parent" and `follow_branch_a` is the parent. Since the `join` task has `one_success` as a requirement it should only run when at least one of the "follow..." tasks succeeds right?

Comment: @SimonD I believe you are right after re-reading the Airflow documentation and the question above - I will revise my answer. Thank you for the feedback!