# Airflow Email Operator Success / Failure

Tags: python, email, airflow

I'm currently working on a DAG that will email a list of users whether the DAG has completed successfully or has failed. I am trying to have the flow of the DAG look like the example here:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

default_args = {
        'owner': 'peter',
        'start_date':datetime(2018,8,11),
}

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='* * * * *',
          default_args = default_args, catchup=False)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

email_success = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to='to@gmail.com',
        subject='Airflow Alert Success',
        html_content=""" <h3>Email Test Success</h3> """,
        dag=dag
)

email_failure = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to='to@gmail.com',
        subject='Airflow Alert Failure',
        html_content=""" <h3>Email Test Failed</h3> """,
        dag=dag
)

hello_operator.set_downstream(email_success,email_failure)
```

Is there a built in operator that I can use with airflow to decide whether the email_success operator is sent when the DAG completes or if email_failure operator is executed when the DAG fails for any reason?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this question while searching for how to get Airflow to email me upon success.

Airflow is able to email on *failure* or *retry* with the following in default_args.

```
default_args = {
    'email': ['some_email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
 }
```

This should help with part of your question regarding failure, and you could use your 'email_success' EmailOperator as the last task in your sequence.

Comment: So the idea of this is that an email will be sent no matter what. If the dag fails on a step before the last operator which would be the email_success operator, that it will send an email stating failure and then stop before hitting the last step. But if it completes all the way through then the email_success operator would execute last and then no failure email is sent?

Comment: Also, if the DAG fails, is there a way to modify the email list depending on user inputs such as an API call or config file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can probably send the failure emails to one email account and the success email to another account by specifying different email address in default_args versus the success EmailOperator 'to='. Regarding, modifying email lists depending on situations which arise within the code itself - you'd need something more complex.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there also an operator it can trigger so that the failure email can be modified?

Comment: No, I dont think so. It's a general failure email. I think you'd need to create specific EmailOperators for the conditions you're looking for. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can can use the `BranchOperator` to decide to send an email on Failure or Success. I have the same scenario whereas I send an email on failure and just ran a DummyOperator if success. 
[image]

You can check this related question about branchOperator [How does Airflow's BranchPythonOperator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526354/how-does-airflows-branchpythonoperator-work)

Comment: If the DAG fails on a step before the branching operator, does that mean an email will not be sent?

Comment: Well, that will be dependent on your trigger_rule. for my example, if my dag have at least one failed task (trigger_rule='one_fail'), it will send an email, otherwise it won't and will skip the the 'send_email' task on branchingOperator. You can see its skip it as it turns pink color.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for are [Trigger Rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules)

You could set the trigger rule for the email that should be sent when nothing fails to `all_success` (default) and the trigger rule for the email that should be sent on failure to `all_failed`.