# Airflow branch errors with object is not iterable

Tags: airflow

I'm trying to get BranchPythonOperator working but I have the following error:

`'BigQueryInsertJobOperator' object is not iterable`

Here is my Branch Operator:

```
branching = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branching',
        python_callable=return_branch,
        provide_context=True)
```

Here is my Python Callable:

```
def return_branch(ds, **kwargs):
    execution_year = kwargs['execution_date'].strftime("%Y")
    type = dataset_metadata[f'{execution_year}']['var']
    if type == 'foo':
        return x
    return y
```

x and y are BigQueryInsertJobOperator:

```
x = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id='x',
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "{% include 'q.sql' %}",
            "use_legacy_sql": False
            }
        },
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: where are you defining `x`? Inside `return_branch`?

Comment: @lionbigcat I've edited my question I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44531885/9682645). Your method, `return_branch`, shouldn't return the operator. It must return the `task_id` of your operator. You'll get something like this:

```py
def return_branch(ds, **kwargs):
    next_task_id = "a" # <some kind of logic>

    return next_task_id


branching = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="pick_query",
    python_callable=return_branch,
    provide_context=True,
)

option_1 = DummyOperator(task_id="a")
option_2 = DummyOperator(task_id="b")

branching >> [option_1, option_2]
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I was justing being confuse because my task and task ID had the same name and my branch wasn't return a string but the operator itself.