# Trigger airflow task based on dynamic variable value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, airflow

I have an airflow DAG which has task of sending an email.

There is a pandas dataframe (df) getting generated as a query output in script.

I would want to send email only if df isn't empty.

How can I trigger/cancel task based on some variable value ( under any if condition ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BranchPythonOperator` to determine whether to skip or run the send email task. Here is a good answer/example on how to set it up.

[How does Airflow's BranchPythonOperator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526354/how-does-airflows-branchpythonoperator-work/44531885).

You will need a python_callable (function) for this Operator to determine if your dataframe is empty/populated.

Comment: The ShortCircuitOperator might be a better fit